# ssl+symmetric with my own encryption algorithm?

Tags: cryptography

I am a final year student currently doing my project, the title is "Mitigating man in the middle attacks using ssl+symmetric key algorithm". I would like to create my own encryption algorithm. I need to know that could I write it in C, and how to generate an ssl key and to write an encryption algorithm and then to combine them both?

Comment: Why do you want to write your own? There are so many good ones already written (and verified).

Comment: I'm not sure that you have done much research on your own for this question. Of course encryption algorithms can be written in C - so many existing ones already have libraries in C.

Comment: Dave, is that you?

Comment: actually i would like to do some creativity,by creating my own concept i could learn a lot and i wanna do my project with my own knowlg.... help me on this

Comment: Then, sure, you have your answer. You can write an encryption algorithm in C. I'm thinking, though, that adding the burden of designing your own algorithm might push back the time it will take to finish your main project.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to [add a symmetric crypto algorithm to OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26673141/is-it-possible-to-add-our-symmetric-algorithm-to-openssl).  There is an example algorithm called [GOST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOST_%28block_cipher%29) included in modern OpenSSL distributions; [this page](http://www.openxpki.org/docs/gost-howto.html) talks a tiny bit about integrating it from a separate package, which would be a good first step for you if you want to learn how to integrate your own algorithm.

That being said, while this would be a useful and interesting learning tool, [never implement your own crypto algorithm](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own) for actual secure use.